# Referencing a custom Shape class in XML

Tags: android, drawable

I have been extending the standard range of `Shape` classes (`RectShape`, `OvalShape` and so on) by extending the `Shape` class to create my own custom set of shapes. For example, I have created a simple `TriangleShape` class, like so:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape;

public class TriangleLeftShape extends Shape {

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    Path path = new Path();
    path.setLastPoint(0, getHeight()/2);
    path.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight());
    path.lineTo(getWidth(), 0);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is create a `Drawable` resource entirely in XML using this class. Is this possible?

I'm aware that using one of the standard shapes is simply achieved by the following example, where the `<shape>` element represents a `ShapeDrawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
<gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

What I cannot see is how one would pass, in XML, a custom `Shape` class to this `ShapeDrawable` that's being defined in XML. I understand that the `android:shape` attribute is simply passing an enum value, which can only be rectangle, oval, line, or ring. It seems that there is no XML attribute to specify a custom `Shape` class.

However, the `ShapeDrawable` has a `setShape()` method, which seems to suggest I could programmatically set my custom `Shape` class, but not do it via XML.

How, if possible, can I make use of a custom `Shape` class in XML? I realise that I could create a custom `View` very easily to draw my basic shapes, but use of `Drawables` seems to have the advantage of being able to specify colours, etc. and other attributes in XML or styles / themes.

Comment: @M.ES In the end I just did it programmatically. I came to the conclusion that what can be done via XML is intentionally limited, and only offers a subset of what can be done via method calls.

Comment: As of Android L Preview, you cannot use custom classes in drawable XML. Also, the <shape> element inflates to GradientDrawable.

Answer (score 1):

Custom drawables cannot be referenced from xml, but you can easily create subclass which can be used in layouts.

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;   
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;


public class TextView extends android.view.TextView {

    public TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setBackground(new MyCustomDrawable());
    }    
}
```

and use it in layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="my textview with custom drawable as background" 
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

By using this trick you can not only set background with custom drawable but also set compound drawables(it class is derived from TextView/Button)